# Strange behaviour when deleting NSTableView item

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a basic NSTableView (view based) without bindings and a tableCellView that includes a couple controls (horizontal slider and a NSStepper).  I use the slider and stepper to adjust values for the particular item associated with the row.  All works as expected, except when I delete an item.

For example if I delete an item then try to select the slider or stepper in row 2, it appears it is also selecting the corresponding control in row 3. I have each of the controls connected to the same Action as follows

```
- (IBAction)percentDidChange:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [_allocationTable rowForView:sender];
    NSLog(@"The row is %ld", (long)row);
}
```

As I try to adjust a control in row 2 the log statement would produce the following

```
The row is 2
The row is 3
The row is -1
```

If I exit this this view and then return all works as expected.

I remove items with the following action

```
- (IBAction)removeSector:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [self.allocationTable rowForView:sender];

    Allocation *allocation = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:row];

    [self.myManagedContext deleteObject:allocation];
    NSError *anyError = nil;
    BOOL success = [self.myManagedContext save:&anyError];
    if (!success) {
        DLog(@"Error:%@", anyError);
    }

    //Update all objects
    [self renumberViewPositions];
    [self updateDataSource];
    [_allocationTable reloadData];
    [self percentCenterTextField];
    [[[self hostView] hostedGraph] reloadData];
}
```

And my Tableview datasource method is

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row
{
    //Setup Number Formatter
    SBIPercentFormatter *percentFormat = [[SBIPercentFormatter alloc] init];

    SBIAllocationCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];

    NSNumber *percentValue = [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"sectorPercentage"];
    NSString *percent = [percentFormat stringFromNumber:percentValue];

    [self updateSectorPopupItems:[result sectorPopUpButton]];
    result.sectorPopUpButton.title = [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"sectorName"];
    result.sectorPercentage.stringValue = percent;
    result.percentStepper.objectValue = percentValue;
    result.mySlider.objectValue = percentValue;
    return result;
}
```

Any ideas what would cause this behaviour?

**EDIT**

Confirmed that this behaviour only occurs when all the tableviewcells are visible if I create enough items that require the scrollview, then works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

1. First try by Setting the Tag of NSStepper/ Slider as the row value in the "viewForTableColumn" method. Something similar to `[mySlider setTag: row];`
2. Then on your method `-(IBAction)percentDidChange:(id)sender` cast the sender appropriately. `NSSlider *tempSlider = (NSSlider*)sender;`
3. Then you can retrieve the correct row by doing

   NSInteger row = [tempSlider tag];
4. Print the values and see

Comment: I tried this and although it no longer returns -1 for a row value it returns all visible rows, row1, row 2, row 3... and moves all corresponding sliders in each row, regardless of which one I select.

Comment: No still struggling to sort it out.  Anymore suggestions? Thanks